# With styled components how to pass theme color from Global Style to React Icons Context Provider?

Tags: styled-components, react-icons, themeprovider

Looking for a way to pass color from theme to React Icons. Theme is working correctly and I'm able to pass colors to my styled components. Here is the breakdown:

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './App'

// Theme
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { GlobalStyles } from './theme/GlobalStyles'
import Theme from './theme/theme'

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

app.js (stripped down):

```js
<IconContext.Provider value={{ color: `${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white}` }}>
  <FaTimes /> 
  <FaBars />
</IconContext.Provider>
```

the equivalent of:

```js
<IconContext.Provider value={{ color: `#fff` }}>
  <FaTimes /> 
  <FaBars />
</IconContext.Provider>
```

does work and I did try:

NavElements.js:

```js
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons/lib'
export const NavProvider = styled(<IconContext.Provider>{children}</IconContext.Provider>)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color2};
`
```

app.js:

```js
// <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: `#fff` }}>
<NavProvider>
  // Further code
</NavProvider> 
// </IconContext.Provider>
```

but I get a children error. Attempt came from reading Q&A [Styled-components and react-icons <IconContext.Provider> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62895878/styled-components-and-react-icons-iconcontext-provider-component)

Other Q&As I found with no luck:

- [How to Style React-Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636280/how-to-style-react-icons)
- [react-icons apply a linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916869/react-icons-apply-a-linear-gradient)

With a theme color in Styled Components how can I pass that color to React Icons Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with `react-icon` but this might help

Take a look at [getting the theme without styled components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#getting-the-theme-without-styled-components) - there is also a [hook](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#via-usecontext-react-hook)

Your example

```
export const NavProvider = styled(<IconContext.Provider>{children}</IconContext.Provider>)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.color2};
`
```

work because `styled` expects a HTML element or a React component

Your `NavProvider` could be something like (haven't tried this code but it should work)

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components';

export const NavProvider = ({children}) => {
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: themeContext.colors.color2 }}>
      {children}
    </IconContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looking around I also found https://github.com/styled-icons/styled-icons - looks like react-icons with styled-components :)

Comment: It worked thanks, the only issue is from `props` because `children` is de-structured so I made an edit.